# How to pass IEnumerable object or data from view to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, radiobuttonfor

I have created a strongly type view. I want to pass IEnumerable Object or data from View to Controller. Following are my **Model**, **Controller** ,**view**

My **Model:**

```
public class UserDetailsClass
{
    public static FeedbackDatabaseDataContext context = new FeedbackDatabaseDataContext(); 
    public class Tablefields
    {
        [Key]
        public  int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]            
        public  string EmailID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Password is required")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")] 
        public  string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")] 
        public string  LastName { get; set; }
    }
    public static List<UserDetails> getalluser()
    {
        var lst = (from r in context.UserDetails select r);
        return lst.ToList();        
    }
 }
```

My **Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Test()
    {

        IList<UserDetailsClass.Tablefields> viewmodel = new List<UserDetailsClass.Tablefields>();
        var q = UserDetailsClass.getalluser().ToList();

        foreach (SQLOperation.Models.UserDetails item in q)
        {
            UserDetailsClass.Tablefields viewItem = new UserDetailsClass.Tablefields();

            viewItem.EmailID = item.Email;
            viewItem.FirstName = item.FirstName;
            viewItem.LastName = item.LastName;
            viewItem.Password = item.Password;

            viewmodel.Add(viewItem);
        }
        return View(viewmodel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(IEnumerable<UserDetailsClass.Tablefields> items)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

My **View**:

```
@model  IEnumerable<SQLOperation.Models.UserDetailsClass.Tablefields>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
 }

 <h2>Test</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        EmailID
    </th>
    <th>
        Password
    </th>
    <th>
        FirstName
    </th>
    <th>
        LastName
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Password)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
    </td>
   </tr> 
   }
</table>
  <input  type="submit" value="submit" />     
}
```

I didn't get any value in **items**.When I set breakpoint on it it show **NULL** in **items**
I am totally Confused about how to pass values to **controller**.

Thank you,
Amol

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.length; i ++)
 {
 <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model[i].EmailID)
    </td>
     <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model[i].Password)
     </td>
     <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model[i].FirstName)
     </td>
     <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model[i].LastName)
     </td>
     </tr> 
   }
 </table>
      <input  type="submit" value="submit" />     
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, I get values in my view but i can't pass it to my controller. in my controller i get NULL

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `@Html.DisplayFor` use `@Html.EditorFor`, that way databinding will happen in your form.

Also since you are using collection you need to iterate your fields (simplified example):

```
                    @for (int row = 0; row < Model.Count; row++)
                    {
                            @Html.EditorFor(x => x[row].FirstName )

                    }
```

Comment: Thank You,
I have changed Html.DisplayFor to Html.EditorFor but I can't get values in controller. It gives NULL

Comment: Edited to reflect that you are sending collection.

Comment: i get error in above x=>x[row].FirstName thats why I change this like following. but still I doesn't get any value in controller  

@for(int row = 0; row < Model.Count(); row++)
 
{ 

         @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ElementAt(row).FirstName)

}

Comment: I get values in Model but i didn't return to controller.